# flask - I can't get to show the output of the second app.route

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

I have this python code for showing temperature and distances (using sensors). The temperature value is shown but the distance value does not. What is wrong with the coding?

I can't seem to work out how to do this. I've tried saving the sensor data output to a text file, dis.txt, but doesn't work still.

Thanks for the help.

Web snapshot:
[websnapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JypTe.png)

python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
import os
#from flask import jsonify
import time
import glob
import sonic
import subprocess
from time import strftime


app = Flask(__name__)

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
os.system('sudo python /home/pi/webserver/sonic.py | tee /home/pi/dis.txt')
temp_sensor='/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0416a2aca1ff/w1_slave'
dista='/home/pi/dis.txt'

@app.route("/")
def tempReading():
    t=open(temp_sensor,'r')
    lines=t.readlines()
    t.close()

    temp_output = lines[1].find('t=')
    if temp_output != -1:
        temp_string=lines[1].strip()[temp_output+2:]
        temp_c=float(temp_string)/1000.0
    templateData = {
        'temp': round(temp_c,1)
    }
    #return jsonify(temp_c)
    return render_template('temp.html',**templateData)

@app.route("/")
def distance():
        t=open(dista,'r')
        lines=t.readlines()
        t.close()

        distance_output = lines[1].find('Distance: ')
    templateData = {
        'dis': distance
    }
    return render_template('temp.html',**templateData)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

temp.html :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--Pescuela, Galilea-->
    <title>Water Quality Monitor</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2"
</head>
    <body>
    <center>
    <font face="Helvetica" size="30">Temperature</font>
    <br><br><strong><font face="Helvetica" size="100">{{ temp }} °C</font></strong>
    <br>
    <font face="Helvetica" size="30">Water level</font>
    <br><br><strong><font face="Helvetica" size="100">{{ dis }} cm</font></strong>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you update your question to include your code as text, not as an image? It's difficult to help when the code isn't easily accessible.

Comment: @alxwrd i've updated it. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.

I though found a way to execute the python script from within the function. I just added `dista=subprocess.check_output('sudo python /home/pi/webserver/sonic.py', shell=True)` , where it gets the output of the script and saves to the variable `dista` and then I added it to the `templateData` dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You've decorated both functions with the base route `"/"`. As it stands, this means that Flask will only run the first function when you hit the base route of your URL.

If you want to keep `distance()` as a separate function, remove the `@app.route` decorator, modify it to return the value you want to display on the page, and then call this function from within your `tempReading()` function, adding the return value to your `templateData` dictionary.